# Where do older versions of apps go when a developer removes them from the App Store

Tags: ios-appstore

so when a developer removes their older versions of their app from the App Store so that you cannot downgrade to them where do they go? for example if an app requires iOS 10 or later and a developer unticks the older versions of their app so that people on lets say iOS 8 cannot download the latest compatible version, what happens? thanks all :)

Comment: This question doesn’t reflect that the App Store can hold and deliver multiple versions of the same app to different iOS. It might need an edit to be answerable. If this is about _how_ the App Store works, it needs an edit. If it’s about how developers decide to use the App Store, it’s likely off topic. Let’s put a hold so it’s clear what Alex is trying to accomplish with this. See [ask] on how to show your research and document what you  believe so that questions don’t need to be closed for clarifying edits.

Comment: App Store Heaven. If they've been good.

Comment: @benwiggy and Blaise Pascal is the digital equivalent of St Peter at the gates... :)

Comment: @bmike what do I have to do to open this question. I have added some more info

Comment: I would start with one question per question

Comment: @bmike do you have any ideas on an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older versions do not "go" anywhere as such. If you're hoping that there would be some kind of "Apple Archives" web site where Apple offers up downloads of older versions that the developer has requested no longer to be used - then you will be disappointed.

When a developer unticks older versions of an app, what happens is that Apple no longer offers that version for redownload from iTunes in the Cloud (i.e. from App Store on a device, iTunes on a computer, etc).

Note that developer often have good reasons for unticking a version. In the end most developers want as many users as possible using their app. It could be for example that an older version no longers work with newer versions of their server software, or that they found a grave bug.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that answered my question. Can developers re-tick those older versions the future if they want to. im trying to look at this from a developers perspective

Comment: Yes, they can indeed recheck them!

Comment: but like you said, there isn't any way that these older versions will accessible to the public. unless the developer rechecks them, there is no way to get that older version, am I right? cheers

Comment: Not from the App Store, no.

Comment: are there any websites that keep them?

Comment: Could you disclose what you want to use it for? The answer might depend on the context

Comment: well, im trying to get an older version of an app. the app is still in the app store but the older versions have been pulled, so i cannot download the latest compatible version

Comment: Okay in that case a web site with downloads won’t help you. You cannot run any app you download from a web site. It must be signed for your device to be able to run it. In all practicality - unless you have the app yourself on a Mac/PC ready to be synced to your device, you can’t really get the older version running.

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the late reply, but i understand that you can download .ipa files (basically a file containing the app) and sign them to your icloud account, and then install the .ipa to my iphone. are there any websites that might keep theseolder versions? i know it’s a long shot but let me know if there is anything i can really do. thanks :)

Comment: Well unless you have a developer account, you’ll need to resign those apps every week.

Comment: i do have a developer account yes. so i think it’s every year i will be needing to re-signing them

Comment: do you know of any websites that keep these older versions?, thank you

Comment: Yet there is a specific dialog offering to download the latest compatible version on older devices/iOS…

Comment: @sambrightman This question is about the situation where the developer specifically has disabled that dialog.